# Facebook API: How to use Event's venue.id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Facebook events have a venue.id, how can I use them? Can they be converted to actual addresses?

For example, the venue id for [this event](http://www.facebook.com/events/278671238901538) is "132764236748017". I found it by running the following fql code,

SELECT venue FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid from event_member WHERE uid= me())

Is 'venue id' the id of a place?

**EDIT: *I found the answer***

I could use 'SELECT name,description,geometry,latitude,longitude,checkin_count,display_subtext FROM place WHERE page_id=110506962309835' where page_id is the same as venue.id